# Confusion regarding IN operator

Tags: mysql, operator-keyword

I'm trying to update two columns in a table using the IN operator as

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET value = value + 1 WHERE column IN ('row1' , 'row2')");
```

but I'm noticing that the value in row1 & row2 is not updating properly as I had thought. I tried with this same code in localhost, it worked but on the test server with about 15-20 hits per hour it is not working. I even blocked the total traffic of the test server and waited for more than 12 hrs if the server is lagging but that didn't help.

I changed my code to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET value = value + 1 WHERE column = 'row1'");
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET value = value + 1 WHERE column = 'row2'");
```

Now I started getting the real-time value even with slightly increased traffic, about 25-30 hits per hour.

Am I making some mistake in the code, took help from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp), or is there any limitation in the IN operator or it is the fault of the test server?

Edit : I'm using a free host.

Comment: `row1` and `row2` is your values, which you want to update?

Comment: Can you share your observations? Since you are incrementing the column value, are you using MySQL internal transactions or transaction scope from code for mutual exclusion? And when you said, it worked in localhost, were you pointing to the same MySQL server or a different one?

Comment: @chiragsatapara No, `row1` and `row2` are two parameters with in the column, say `Cat` and `Dog` in two separate rows in the column `Animals` and let value be `count`.

Something like,

_mysql_query("UPDATE table SET count = count + 1 WHERE column IN ('Cat' , 'Dog')");_

Comment: @SunilSinghal I'm pointing to a different one on the test server. Not sure if the traffic is responsible for it. In the test server, it is updating with a lag, as a result, some values are not recorded. 

I'm not using any sort of MySQL transactions. I have just kept that line within a if statement.

Comment: And, what was the traffic pattern when you observed this?

Comment: What database engine is the affected table using? During write operations InnoDB utilizes row-level locking, while MyISAM utilizes table-level locking. Additionally can you provide an actual query utilized, aside from focusing on `IN`. Based on the observed behavior it sounds like a race condition is occurring on the criteria, where a concurrent query would fail to update, due to previous row values changing once the lock has been released and the next query in queue is processed.

Comment: @SunilSinghal It has approximately an even traffic. as it is on the test server (free host) I have full control over its traffic.

Comment: @fyrye the DB is in InnoDB

The actual query is a simple one, first, it will check if the person is a new user then it will `INSERT` else `UPDATE` two rows.

More importantly where I'm getting more confused is that all other queries with `IN` are working fine only this is not working. :(

Comment: @NewBee please update your question with a sample of actual process(es) that issues queries to the MySQL server during the request/session, so we can get a grasp on what exactly maybe happening within the session that is causing the undesirable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is the classical case of race and use of no synchronization technique to create mutual exclusion block. Try executing this update statement within a transaction

Comment: I read in an ebook that the `TRANSACTION ` feature demands more resource so I avoided it.

However, if it goes to `ROLLBACK` state then nothing will be recorded will I be able to track the lost data.

I'm completely new to this & this is my first site so sorry for my novice replies.

Comment: @NewBee Transactions offer an all or nothing "unit of work" approach, that is important if you write to multiple tables in a single request/session, such as processing customer orders. Preventing an undesired write if a query within the transaction fails. Rollbacks occur when a query fails. Allowing you to handle the failure at application level, with the ability to rollback to a given `SAVEPOINT`.

Comment: @SunilSinghal @fyrye thanks for the suggestion about `TRANSACTION`. In my current usage, the lag will not impact users' accounts or anything within the site but in other situation, it might create a havoc. I'll try to modify all the `IN` and separately updated tables to `TRANSACTION`. :)